# Parse a recipe and determine if gluten free

Tags: ruby, nlp

I have been assigned an application where a user types in ingredients for a recipe and I try and figure out things like if the recipe is vegan, vegetarian, or gluten free. I'm trying to figure out how to determine how a recipe is gluten free.

Say I have the following ingredients typed in:

```
2 Tbsp olive oil
2 large onion, chopped
4 large garlic cloves, minced
2 large carrots, peeled and sliced
1/3 cup of raw white rice 
2 pounds ground beef
3/4 cup of chopped fresh mint leaves
```

How can I programmatically determine if the recipe is gluten free. Is defining a list of gluten-containing foods, and checking if the ingredients typed in don't match, be the most efficient way?

Comment: Yes, the only definitive way to ensure that a recipe is gluten free would be to test each ingredient against a list of possible ingredients that contain gluten. You also need to consider normalizing pluralization, synonyms, case, etc... What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you had a corpus of existing recipes that were labelled as containing gluten or not, you could create a machine learning algorithm that inferred the ingredients responsible.